# Alert Box in Android doesn't let me to click, just directly performs the action

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I've a button upon clicking should display an alertdialog box containing just "OK" button and upon clicking should go to another activity. But this dialog box appears for a few seconds and goes to the activity without letting me click or confirm it. This is the code i've used

```
   public void onClick(View v) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(InsertData.this);

    alertbox.setMessage("Object Location Stored!");

    alertbox.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // the button was clicked

                Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(a);
            }

        });
        alertbox.show();

    }
```

Can anyone pls help me resolve this? Thanks in adv..

Comment: This code looks correct to me - can you post the rest of your code, particularly the code that where you create your alertbox.

Comment: shouldn't your code be inside an if condition. I mean any view with listener when touched will execute the piece of code you've posted.... just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what the problem is. A few days ago, I tried to include an AlertDialog myself. I saw that there are a lot of deprecated methods. I ended up using the code below. Try this if you like

```
AlertDialog ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        ad.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        ad.setMessage("MESSAGE");
        ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }}); 
        ad.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres an idea, lets see if your alertDialogs onClick is even being called. This will tell you if your problem is with the alert dialog or with something else. You should be able to copy and paste this into your app and then just call showAlertDialog(); from where ever you want.  Post the code where your alertDialog is called from.

```
public void showAlertDialog()
{

         AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog
            .Builder(YourActivity.this);
     alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Look at me!");
     alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Im an alert dialog")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setNegativeButton("Okay",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) 
                {

                    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Alert dialog onClick",   
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            }
        );

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```