# Cannot close alertdialog completely

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a customized alertdialog with the delete and cancel functions. delete button is to delete the current selected list item. cancel button should close the alertdialog and go back to the list.. When I click on delete, it will delete it and when I click on cancel, it will close the alertdialog and go to the list. However, when I click on the backbutton, it shows the alert dialog again. Here is the code snippet for my alert dialog:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grocerylistdelete, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder abuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);
            abuilder.setView(v);
            TextView tvStatement = (TextView)   v.findViewById(R.id.textViewStatementDelete);
            tvStatement.setTypeface(bold);
            tvStatement.setText("Are you sure you want to delete"+" "+mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ITEM))+"?");


            Button delete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
            delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Cursor c = db.getAllGroceries();
                    c.moveToPosition(info.position);
                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.ROW_ID));
                    db.open();
                    db.deletegrocery(Long.parseLong(id)); 
                    c.close();

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(GroceryList.this, "Item Deleted Successfully", 5000);
                    toast.show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GroceryList.class);
                    fillData();
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
                Button canceldelete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancelDelete);
                canceldelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GroceryList.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });

                abuilder.setCancelable(false);
                AlertDialog alert2 = abuilder.create();
                alert2.show();
```

Comment: What was the scope of that alert2.show(); When you navigate to previous page, it will calls again..

Comment: How can I make the back button not call the alertdialog again?

Comment: That's odd. I thought the whole point of `abuilder.setCancelable(false);` was to prevent the back button from affecting the dialogs!

Comment: @manavo - abuilder.setCancelable(false) would disable the backbutton when you are on the alertdialog state. After clicking on cancel, it will go back to the list, but when I hit the back button WHILE ON THE LIST, it will show the alertdialog again.

Comment: could you check this page? It might require you to change the code a bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125520/alert-box-in-android-doesnt-let-me-to-click-just-directly-performs-the-action/11125812#11125812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaaah, I see it now. When you click the buttons, you start a new activity, which looks like it is actually the same activity as the one you are now.

So essentially, what's happening is you start a new activity, and the old one is still there, with the alertdialog still open.

Instead, you could refresh the data in your current list, without starting a new activity. To do this, you can hide the AlertDialog with the `dismiss()` method once someone has clicked (instead of starting a new activity).

If you do prefer to start a new activity, then the best thing to do would be to `finish()` the current one.

Comment: Using that finished the alertdialog including the currentactivity, but came back to the current activity because of the intent.